# Потомок от std::set с лямбда функцией сравнения

Tags: c++

```
#include <set>
#include <functional>

class C
{
public:
    C(const std::string& address) :
        mAddress(address)
    {};
    virtual const std::string& Address() const
    { 
        return mAddress;
    };
private:
    std::string mAddress;
};

class SetC :public std::set<C*, std::function<bool(const C*, const C*)>>
{
};
```

Подскажите где прописать код лямбда функции сравнения, например, такой:

```
[](const C* pC1, const C* pC2) {return pC1->Address() < pC2->Address(); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [конструкторе](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set):

```
using Comp = std::function<bool(const C*, const C*)>;
SetC()
    : std::set<C*, Comp>(
            Comp([](const C* pC1, const C* pC2) {
                    return pC1->Address() < pC2->Address();
            }))
{}
```

При этом вообще STL-контейнеры не очень хорошо переносят хранение указателей (кто-то должен отдельно за этими указателями следить; для векторов явственно нарушается locality и т.п.). Плюс виртуальный метод, возвращающий ссылку на строку тоже выглядит таинственно и необычно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Указатели и виртуальный метод для того, чтобы хранить в контейнере полиморфные объекты.

Comment: Ну да, логично. Про деструктор не забудьте. :-)

Comment: Да, конечно :) Спасибо за помощь!